# How to easily speed up video in command line?

Tags: macos, command-line

The only way I know how is via `ffmpeg`, and the commands are so long and difficult, especially when trying to speed up the video and its audio at the same time and keep them in sync.

Is there an easier more brainless way I can save a sped-up version of a video file and its audio from the command line?

Comment: You could write a shell script with the long and difficult commands, so you would only need to get it right once.